# Return Missing on NONE object

Tags: python

I have an object I'm creating and sometimes it's not going to be created i.e. `None`.

I perform the following 
`dic.get("findThis")` but since `dic` is sometimes `None` It will return `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

There are a few solutions like checking the `dic` for existence using

```
if not dic: 
  print "MISSING" 
else: 
  #do your stuff`.
```

What's a better way to do this?

Comment: Without the context of your specific problem I think your approach is the best on those cases. But maybe in a more specific situation there is a better way.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your solution. unless you don't want to print missing for an empty dict, in which case you'd want to do if dic is not None

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a ternary operator?

`result = dic.get("findThis") if dic else None`

Comment: No that's not it. For example let's say I do something like 
`[dic.get("findThis"),dic.get("findThis2"),dic.get("findThis3"),dic.get("findThis4"),dic.get("findThis5"),dic.get("findThis6")]`, They should all return "MISSING" and not have to do a check for each.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why is it possible for dic to become None, it seems like you should just use an empty dict instead of None as a default value.

Comment: The `dic` is returned from a json response sometimes it's missing.

Comment: Then why don't you check it once and substitute with empty dict if it's None? It's common practice to do smth like `if not x: x = {}` Especially when passing empty parameters to a function or deserialising some values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `defaultdict` an use it like this:

```
import collections

#example function returning the dict
def get_dict_from_json_response():
    return {'findThis2':'FOUND!'}

defdic = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 'MISSING')

#get your dict
dic = get_dict_from_json_response()

if dic:
   defdic.update(dic) #copy values

dic = defdic #now use defaultdict
print [dic["findThis"],dic["findThis2"],dic["findThis3"],dic["findThis4"],dic["findThis5"],dic["findThis6"]]
```

Output:

```
['MISSING', 'FOUND!', 'MISSING', 'MISSING', 'MISSING', 'MISSING']
```